# XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: application.properties is invalid, SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to migrate an old spring application, with java 1.7, to springboot 1.5.6.RELEASE.
I added all the necessary dependencies:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependencies>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependencies>
             <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
             <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
             <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
         </dependency>
```

I created the Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "en.zerouno.jp3")
@ImportResource({ ..., "classpath:applicationContext-data.xml", "classpath:application.properties", ... })
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

I moved the config files under src/main/resources.
I've checked the properties file over and over and it doesn't seem to contain any special characters (or BOM). In fact, when I try to start the Tomcat server I get the following error even if I were to put a single line in the application.properties file, eg: 'debug:true'

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [application.properties] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:353) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationCont.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at it.zerouno.jp3.application.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

What else could cause this error?
I also tried using the application.yml file instead of application.properties but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that it is trying to parse the properties files as it was a Spring XML file. Maybe it is referenced incorrectly somewhere?

Comment: where can i check this? I don't seem to see anything in my application that is trying to read an xml file. I took the same files and configurations of the old Spring application, which used the application.properties file.
The only xml it tries to read are the applicationContext-xxx.xml, but the error signals it only on the application.properties.
If I try to delete the contents of the file, it correctly reports me another type of error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I removed the properties files from the @ImportResource annotation, because otherwise they are read as XML. @Aled thanks for the tip.

I had to create the following class to make the properties file read before the XML files are read:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
     PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc
         = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]
         { new ClassPathResource("application.properties"), new ClassPathResource("integration.properties"),
             new ClassPathResource("doprint.properties"), new ClassPathResource("application-personal.properties") };
     pspc.setLocations( resources );
     pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
     return pspc;
   }
}
```